# Is there a function similar to OpenCV findContours that detects curves and replaces points with a spline?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to take the below image, trace the white shape, and export the resulting path to pdf. The problem I have is that findContours seeming only finds points along the edge of the shape. Is there a solution out there, similar to findContours, that detects curves in a shape and replaces its points with a spline wherever there is a curve? If I use scipy.interpolate it ignores straight lines and turns the entire contour into one big curved shape, which is no good either. I need something that does both things.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
from pyx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read in image file                                                             
original = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

#blur the image to smooth edges                                                 
im = cv2.medianBlur(original,5)

#threshold the image                                                            
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)                                                             

#findContours                                                                   
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_\
APPROX_SIMPLE)

#drawContours
cv2.drawContours(original, [approx], -1, (0,255,0), 3)                          
cv2.imshow("Imageee", original)                                                 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points) helps ?

Comment: The solution in that thread @ZdaR would make the entire pattern rounded. I think op is looking for straight lines on the outside edges and curved where need be.

Comment: One solution would be to take the points of the contour which make up the convex hull, which correspond to the points which don't need to fit the curve. Then the points left will be those from the curve, and you can fit a spline to just that section.

Answer (score 6):

Except using `cv2.findContours` with flag `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` to approx the contours, we can do it manually.

1. use `cv2.findContours` with flag `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` to find contours.
2. use `cv2.arcLength` to calculate the contour length.
3. use `cv2.approxPoolyDP` to approx the contour manually with `epsilon = eps * arclen`.

---

Here is one of the results when `eps=0.005`:

[image]

More results:

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.04 13:01:24 CST
# 2018.01.04 14:42:58 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,threshed = cv2.threshold(gray,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# find contours without approx
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

# get the max-area contour
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]

# calc arclentgh
arclen = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)

# do approx
eps = 0.0005
epsilon = arclen * eps
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)

# draw the result
canvas = img.copy()
for pt in approx:
    cv2.circle(canvas, (pt[0][0], pt[0][1]), 7, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.drawContours(canvas, [approx], -1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

# save
cv2.imwrite("result.png", canvas)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem actually consists of two issues.

The first issue is to extract the contour, which you can achieve using teh findContour function:

```
import numpy as np

print cv2.__version__

rMaskgray = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
(thresh, binRed) = cv2.threshold(rMaskgray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, Rcontours, hier_r = cv2.findContours(binRed,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
r_areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in Rcontours]
max_rarea = np.argmax(r_areas)
CntExternalMask = np.ones(binRed.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255

contour= Rcontours[max_rarea]
cv2.drawContours(CntExternalMask,[contour],-1,0,1)
print "These are the contour points:"
print c
print
print "shape: ", c.shape

for p in contour:
    print p[0][0]
    cv2.circle(CntExternalMask, (p[0][0], p[0][1]), 5, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imwrite("contour.jpg", CntExternalMask)
cv2.imshow("Contour image", CntExternalMask)                                                 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you execute the program, the contour points are printed as a list of point coordinates.

The contour approximation method you choose influences the interpolation which is actually used (and the number of points found), as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). I have added small dots at the points found with the approximation method cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE. You see that the straight lines are already approximated.

[image]

I may not fully have understood your second step, though. You want to omit some of those points, replacing point lists partially by splines. There might be different way to do this, depending on your final intention. Do you just want to replace the straight lines? If you replace curved parts, what is the margin of error you are allowing?

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough response. I hope you have had a joyful holiday season. I want to replace curves in the path with splines. As far as margin of error, I would like splines to pass through >95% of the points. Multiple splines are fine. Your response has me thinking that a good approach would be to detect all straight lines in the contour, and to omit those points, then to apply scipy.interpolate to the remaining points, connecting all the dots at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import glob
import cv2
#For saving pdf 
def save_pdf(imagename):
  import img2pdf
  # opening from filename
  with open("output.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(imagename))
#for fouind biggest contours
def bigercnt(contours):
  max_area=0
  cnt=[]
  for ii in contours:
    area=cv2.contourArea(ii)
    if area>max_area:
      cnt = ii
  return cnt
#STARTING
print ("Reading img.jpg file")
# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 
print ("Converting it gray scale")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print ("Bluring")
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
print ("Looking for edges" )
# apply Canny edge detection using a wide threshold, tight
# threshold, and automatically determined threshold
tight = cv2.Canny(blurred, 255, 250)
print ("Looking for contours")
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10, 10))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(tight, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( close.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("Looking for big contour")
cnt = bigercnt(contours)
print ("Cropping found contour")
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
croped_image = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
img2 = np.zeros((h,w,4),np.uint8)      
print ("Taking only pixels in countour and creating png")
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
      #print (x+j, y+i)
      #print   cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x+j, y+i), False)
      if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (x+j, y+i), False)==1:    
        #print True
        img2[i,j] = [croped_image[i, j][0],croped_image[i, j][1],croped_image[i, j][2],255]
      else:
        img2[i,j] = [255,255,255,0]
print ("Showing output image")
# Show the output image
#cv2.imshow('croped', croped_image)
cv2.imshow('output', img2)
params = list()
params.append(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION)
params.append(8)
print ("Saving output image")
cv2.imwrite("output.png",img2,params)
print ("Finish:converted")
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, do not only post code